# How to identify if row changed in SAP ASE 16.0

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I have a SAP ASE 16.0 SP02 PL06 and would like to know if the data of the row changed.

My use-case is that I have a table with the data and the same table with all previous statuses of all rows (it is history of the "data evolution", if you like) plus some auditing columns (`rowID`, `historizationDate`). And I need to know if the last historized version and the current version of a given row differs.

First I was overjoyed by [`HASH()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1600/doc/html/san1393050455178.html) function until I found it takes only single piece of data, e.g. one cell, constant or combination of those. Then my idea moved to ugly and dirty hack: concatenate all columns of the given row and compare those directly (this leads to a lot of `convert(varchar, column)`, but no hashing).

Are there better solution with the respect to the constraints given bellow?

Constraints: I cannot alter the original table, solution has to be as fast as reasonably possible (high throughput through table, high concurrency, literally the heart of whole database) and the source table has a 4-column primary key and high 10´s of columns overall. No sensitive data (like passwords) which needs hashing are present.

Drastically simplified structure of tables:

Original:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  dataID       int, 
  column1      int, 
  column2      datetime, 
  ...)
```

History:

```
CREATE TABLE dataHistory (
  rowID              int         identity, 
  historizationDate  datetime    default getDate(), 
  dataID             int, 
  column1            int, 
  column2            datetime, 
  ...)
```

---

**EDIT**: As per @markp´s comment: The table is not accessed directly by user, but through a stored procedure. So when all checking/preparation is done, then data are saved into the table. The problem is that after all checking the new data can be rejected. Not because some invalidity/referential integrity/etc., but because the source of data is deemed less reliable then data already present. This checking is done through a few dozens procedures nested several layers deep and for each column separately, so alternating all those procedures to see if/what they did to the data is not a very viable solution... (Yes, the system is very well matured having some 20 years of age.)

The final use of all those historized data is to see what data was present in the database at any given moment to draw some business conclusions from them (e.g. how often or how much are those data changed, if operational procedures are adhered to and similar uses).

Comment: how is the history table maintained? by a trigger? by hoping the user/application makes sure it's updated when the main table is updated? [objective is to understand why you're trying to find rows that are 'out of sync']

Comment: 'The problem is that after all checking the new data can be rejected.' - which new data the data in the main data table or dataHistory?

Comment: New data can be rejected from the main table. Table dataHistory is just a dumb copy copy of main table in any given time. And I want to save space by chcecking if change acutally happened, so I do not have n-times same row (aside from auditing columns).

Answer (score 0):

> First I was overjoyed by HASH() function until I found it takes only single piece of data, e.g. one cell, constant or combination of those. Then my idea moved to ugly and dirty hack: concatenate all columns of the given row and compare those directly

SAP ASE also has a [hashbytes()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2df920cd5b1644e5a065d55b637d5e92/LATEST/en-US/aad2d7bfbc2b1014babaa254e16414ec.html) function that can do something like this:

```
select hashbytes('sha1',col1,col2,col3) from mytable
```

Note, in some versions of ASE 16, using 'md5' with hashbytes() causes major memory leakage.  You can't use "*" for the column list.